# Is there a way to condense this code?

Tags: r, iteration

Is there a way to condense code like this? In this case B is just a column vector and A is just a scalar value. I feel as if the line Q1 <- A*(1+B[1]) will have to stay like that and then rest of the code can probably be written in a much cleaner way.

```
Q1 <- A*(1+B[1])

Q2 <- Q1*(1+B[2])

Q3  <- Q2*(1+B[3])

Q4 <- Q3*(1+B[4])

Q5 <- Q4*(1+B[5])

QCombo <- matrix(c(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The desired out come would be a column vector.

Comment: You should provide `A` and `B` in your question.

Comment: @nrussel you are correct, this is a bad way to ask a question.

Comment: The topic of your question is fine, you just need to provide a completely reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `cumprod` (Using @MrFlick's example)

```
A*cumprod(B+1)
#[1]   20   60  240 1200 7200
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your A and B look something like this

```
A <- 10
B <- 1:5
```

This looks like a good use of the `Reduce` function

```
Reduce(function(a,b) a*(1+b), B, init=A, accumulate=T)[-1]
# [1]   20   60  240 1200 7200
```

We use `[-1]` to trim off the initial `A` value. You can wrap them in a `matrix()` call if you really need to.